# How do I show the progress of the stream without a uislider?

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

I don't want to use a uislider, instead I want to use a progress view to show the progress of the song completed, just like spotify on the bottom.

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressbar: UIProgressView!

func playSong(){
self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        print(url)
        print("time \(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player.currentItem?.asset.duration)!))") //I Get the correct time printed

        self.player.volume = 1.0
        self.player.rate = 1.0
        self.player.play()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to use progress view instead of slider. You can start from [here](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/progress-view-tutorial-in-ios8-with-swift).

[Here](https://github.com/yannickl/YLProgressBar) is nice objective-c framework for the progress bars.